# Measure computational complexity of solving a linear system Ax=b by increasing size of A

Tags: algorithm, matlab, time-complexity

I have a linear equation

```
Ax=b
```

where `A` is non-singular matrix `N×N`, and `x,b` are vector `N×1`; `A,b` are given and I want to find x

It is clear that x can be found by x=A^(−1)*b. I would like to measure  the computational complexity when `N` increasing.

In MATLAB, I used the code x=A\b. I know that MATLAB will choose a best algorithm to find the solution. In analysis, I know that the computational complexity grows as N^3 when N is increases. How can I fit/measure computational complexity between simulation and analysis of above equation when N increasing?

Comment: Measure how long it takes to run at different values of `N`, store `N` and the amount of time in an array, and plot them.

Comment: See [`timeit`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) to accurately measure computation time

Comment: Do you think that simulation will be show exactly the analysis result as N^3? Because MATLAB choose the best algorithm if i use A\b

Answer (score 2):

According to the [linear solver flowchart](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html), for random matrices `A = rand(n)` the solver will use LU factorization (essentially Gaussian elimination) since all other algorithms require some special form of the matrix.

The count of required operations is of order N^3. But this does not translate into N^3 running time, because the numerical linear algebra routines in MATLAB [are multithreaded](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-multicore.html).  E.g., when performing Gaussian elimination on some column, the row operations can be performed independently and thus may be distributed between several threads.

Here is how I tested the running time of linear solver. The matrix sizes are `100:10:500`. I repeat `A\b` 500 times, with the same matrix (to avoid adding the cost of generating these matrices to the total).

```
sizes = 100:10:500;
tries = 500;
n = numel(sizes);
time = zeros(1, n);
for j = 1:n
    A = rand(sizes(j));
    b = rand(sizes(j), 1);
    tic 
    for k = 1:tries
        x = A\b;
    end
    time(j) = toc;
end
logsize = log(sizes/sizes(1));
logtime = log(time/time(1));
plot(sizes, logtime./logsize);
axis([sizes(1) sizes(end) 0 4])
```

Instead of looking at `plot(sizes, time)` and trying to figure out if it's cubic or what, I take the ratio of logarithms that is meant to show the exponent of N directly. It looks  like this on my machine, indicating approximately N^2 growth.

[image: order]

(As Luis Mendo noted, using `timeit` instead of `tic`, `toc` would be better, but it's not available in my old version of MATLAB.)

Comment: Thank Sally. Is it possible to turn of multithreaded to fit analysis and simulation?